# MaterializeCSS carousel set start image without effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I'm trying to set the start position in a fullscreen `MaterializeCSS` carousel. I want to use it as a gallery image viewer inside a fullscreen modal. 
Once gallery image is clicked, the `modal` opens and the image slider should start at the clicked image. Inside the documentation of `MaterializeCSS` I couldn't find any important information for that.

Currently the carousel slides to the right image. I only want to delete the slide effect `on start` and activate it after viewing the first image.

Two of many images to open:

```
<div class="gallery-item-left col s12 m6">
    <img class="responsive-img gallery-item" alt="gallery-image-1" data-position="1" src="...path-to-image-1..." />
</div>
<div class="gallery-item-right col s12 m6">
    <img class="responsive-img gallery-item" alt="gallery-image-2" data-position="2" src="...path-to-image-2..." />
</div>
...
```

My jQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.gallery-item', function() {
        var position = $(this).data('position');
        $('#img-viewer-modal').modal('open');
        $('#img-viewer-carousel').carousel({fullWidth: true, duration: 400});
        $('#img-viewer-carousel').carousel('set', [position - 1]);
});
```

**#img-viewer-carousel** is simply the carousel id inside my modal.

I'm very thankful for every tip.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the generated HTML. not PHP.

Comment: The only way I see is to dynamicly build the html code inside the carousel after clicking the selected image. In this case the selected image has to be the first image in the carousel.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I've found is to dynamicly change the content items of the carousel.

See example under https://www.codeply.com/go/EiubFqcKcg